# How to control the UITableViewCell style programmatically?

Tags: uitableview

Being working with StoryBoard I have this situation, with the code below:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"CELL_TEXT"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[cityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"DETAIL_TEXT"];
```

My tests show me that regardless of the fact that I use UITableViewCellStyleDefault, or UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle when performing the alloc, the two last lines of code above will work.

Those two last lines are only depending on my settings in the StoryBoard (cell style to Subtitle or not).

Now here is my question: How can I programmaticaly control the style of the cells, going from UITableViewCellStyleDefault to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and vice versa?

Obviously, changing the alloc only, does not work; and I did not find any property that I could set either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Storyboard with a prototype cell, the cell will not be nil. It will always be created. Either don't use a prototype cell in a Storyboard or allocate a different protoype cell from the Storyboard.

Comment: What do I do if I want to change the type of the cells while the application is running? I suppose the first thing is not to use a prototype cell in a Storyboard? But what else?